# Assign values from service response to list of objects

Tags: c#

I have the following code in which I am getting result from service as below :

```
var result=CallService();
 response.Alllist = new List<Check>
                {
                    new Check
                    {
                        Bundle1 = new Bundle
                        {
                            Documents = new List<Document>
                            {
                                new Document(), new Document()
                            }
                        },


                    },
                    new CheckList
                    {
                        Bundle1 = new Bundle
                        {
                            Documents = new List<Document>
                            {
                                new Document(), new Document()
                            }
                        },
                    }
```

And I am struggling in assigning values to this.
And the response class is

```
    public class Response
        {
            [DataMember(Order = 1)]
            public bool Response { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 2)]
            public List<Check> Alllist { get; set; }
        }

public class Document
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    }


    public class Bundle
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string BundleName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string DocumentCategory { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public string NextBundleName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    }


    public class Check
    {

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string TransactionID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public Bundle Bundle1 { get; set; }
    }
```

And the service returns ,two instances of system.collection.generic.list with multiple instances. and it returns the values of 
BundleName,
DocumentCategory ,
NextBundleName ,
DocumentType ,
DocumentName.

How to take result value and assign to this response?
I am trying to assign like this

```
           int count=0;
            foreach (var c in result)
            {
                response.Alllist[count].Bundle1.BundleName = c
            }
```

but since result is dynamic , I am not able to fetch value as c.BundleName

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: is your service returning JSON? If yes then why not use a DTO?

Comment: No its a list of fields which service returns

Comment: Well, what is `result`?

Comment: As i have mentioned in my question, result is a Generic collection of list containing fields like Bundlename,document name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `response.Alllist` is a `List<Check>` as you demonstrated in your first code block, you can populate the values in this manner:

```
response.Alllist[0].Bundle1.DocumentCategory = "my category";
response.Alllist[0].Bundle1.Documents[0].DocumentName  = "my doc name";
```

and so on.

Other than that, I really don't know what else to tell you.  I'm assuming you know about addressing collections by index, etc.  You just have to look at the class composition hierarchy in your second code block, i.e. what classes contain instances or collections of other classes.

Comment: I meant result variable is also list. So I thought there should be any looping or lambda expression to accomplish this

Comment: Will it not throw NRE or outofrange exception since `response.Alllist` is NULL

Comment: @Rahul Maybe I'm not understanding the context here, but the first code block sets up the composition hierarchy, i.e. `response.Alllist = ...` with the object initializers, so no null refs.

Comment: @user3331421 -- Well, I gave a stab at it.  I just don't know what your question is.

Comment: Yeah, I don't blame you ... question is really very unclear that I stopped from posting an answer. But by any means your answer could be a good start for OP.

Comment: Updated my question with what I am tryinh

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, In similar situation, I have tried something like below. Hope this helps. myclass is class define in my project containing field.

```
 Guid testGuid = guid.empty;
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(testData.customerAccountURL).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string JSONResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var rObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myclass>>(JSONResponse);
                testGuid = Guid.Parse(rObjects.First().field1.ToString());
                // now use this guid to search for a customer
            }

            string GuidURL = URL + "/"+ testGuid;
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GuidURL);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(result);
                string data = values.ElementAt(0).Value;
            }
        }
```